# Complex integration problem via Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I want to integrate the following :$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{dz}{z^{2}-1}$$ in the positive direction.

So my idea is two split the integral into a sum of two integral , something like $$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{dz}{z-1}+\int_{|z|=2} \frac{dz}{z+1}$$ since $$(z-1)(z+1)=z^{2}-1$$ and then proceed by applying Cauchy's integral formula since the poles of each function in the sum of integral is inside the circle $|z|=2$.

The only problem is how to correctly split the function into a sum of two functions? Is my idea right in order to solve the integral? Thanks

Comment: This works but it's completely useless. Cauchy integral formula works directly on the function $\frac 1{z^2-1}$.. Why do you want to split it?

Comment: @Ant Probably because (the usual formulation of) Cauchy's integral formula requires the integrand to be of the form $$\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$$ where $f$ is holomorphic. In particular, the integrand can only have one pole inside the curve. To use Cauchy's integral formula here, we need to split the curve or the function. (Of course, once we have residue calculus there are quicker approaches.)

Comment: @mrf Ah, right :-) Thanks for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**
$$\frac{1}{z^2-1} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{(z-1)(z+1)} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{(z+1)-(z-1)}{(z+1)(z-1)} = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg(\frac{\color{red}{z+1}}{\color{red}{(z+1)}(z-1)}-\frac{\color{blue}{z-1}}{(z+1)\color{blue}{(z-1)}}\Bigg) = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}\Bigg) $$

Now you can proceed as you stated.

But what is Cauchy Index Theorem? I haven't heard of it. I assume you meant Cauchy Integral Theorem?

Comment: Sorry , I meant Cauchy integral formula ,haha. Thanks , Aritra

Comment: @Cos If you think this answer was useful, kindly upvote it. If you think it is the one among all others that best answered your question, accept it by clicking on the grey tick mark below the up/down vote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is by partial fractions. Here is the general method:

You want $A,B$ with 
$$\frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{z+1}=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)}$$ Then we have:

$A(z+1)+B(z-1)=1\Rightarrow (A+B)z+A-B=1$ for all $z$ then $A=-B$ and $A-B=1\Rightarrow -2B=1$ and $B=-1/2$ and $A=1/2$. And now you have the integral you would like to evaluate.