# How can I make sense of this basic algebraic manipulation backwards?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

$$\frac{1}{n^2-1} = \frac12\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1}\right)$$

It is easy for me to understand this algebraic from *right to left* ←, but I struggle to find a reasonable way to work from left to right.

Regarding expected difficulty, the level of algebraic manipulated is here meant for a Calculus II course.

Thanks all.

Comment: This is a special case of partial fraction decomposition. Check it out here:
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm

Comment: Check out the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1768945/229480 Though the premise of that question is absolutely different, the answers are absolutely same.

Comment: It's hard for me too, so you aren't alone.  However to to work that way we need an idea of a goal we are working toward.  If the idea is to rewrite 1/f (n)g (n) as w/f (n) + v/g (n) we know we want w/n-1 + v/n+1 with w (n+1) + v (n-1)=1.  To get the n's to vanish we know v = -w and so we have  2w = 1 so w = 1/2, v=-1/2 and ... well that's it really.

Comment: ...or another way of thinking of it:  we want to "separate" the $n-1$ and $n+1$ in the denominator so want to have some $n$'s in a sum so there'll be an $n+1$ and an $n-1$ to factor in the sum.  So we "antimatter" "opposing"  $n$'s in.  $1/(n^2 - 1) = n-n+1/n^2 -1$.  But we need another $1$.  We can't "antimatter" lopsided things in, so we have to split the $1$ evenly.  $1= n+1/2 - n+ 1/2$.  But now we need to scale the $n$'s in proportion to the $1/2$s.  $\frac {1=1/2+1/2=n/2+1/2 -n/2+1/2=1/2 (n+1)-1/2 (n-1)} {n^2-1}=\frac {1/2 (n+1)}{n^2-1}-\frac{1/2 (n-1)}{n^2-1} $.

Answer (score 3):

Write $$R = \frac{1}{n^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{(n - 1)(n + 1)}$$

Now, we wish to decompose $R$ into something with denominator $(n - 1)$ and denominator $(n + 1)$

The standard way to do this is by a method knows as "partial fractions". We assign $R$ to

$$R = \frac{A}{n - 1} + \frac{B}{n + 1} = \frac{1}{(n - 1)(n + 1)}$$

Cross multiplying,

$$R = \frac{A (n + 1) + B (n - 1)}{(n - 1)(n + 1)} = \frac{1}{(n - 1)(n + 1)}
$$

Since the denominators are equal, we can simply equate the numerators and see what values of A, B we need.

$$
A(n + 1) + B(n - 1) = 1 + 0n \\
(A - B) + n(A + B) = 1 + 0n
$$

Clearly, we have two inequalities (by assigining the coefficients of the constant term and $n$ to each other.

$$
A - B = 1 \\
A + B = 0
$$

Substituting $B = -A$ in the first equation,

$$
A - (-A) = 1 \\
2A = 1 \\
A = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Substituting $A = \frac{1}{2}$ in $A + B = 0$ gives $B = \frac{-1}{2}$

Hence, $$R = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{n - 1} + \frac{\frac{-1}{2}}{n + 1} \\
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n - 1} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Think about passing to a common denominator, in reverse: whenever we see a fraction of the form ${a\over b\cdot c}$, we should *expect* it to equal ${x\over b}+{y\over c}$ for some reasonable $x, y$.

In fact, once we get this idea, it's not hard to see that this will happen whenever $x$ and $y$ satisfy $$xc+yb=a.$$ Of course, this is sort of "right-to-left" as far as the OP goes, but it's motivated by the left-to-right direction. OK, so let's look at the specific case. Here, $a=1$, $b=n-1$, $c=n+1$ (since $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$). So we want $x$ and $y$ to satisfy $$x(n+1)+y(n-1)=1.$$ This might look messy, but we have one more trick: *we want $x$ and $y$ to be just numbers, not expressions in terms of $n$.* (Why? Well, just because if we could, that'd make our lives easier. :P) If this is going to work, though, then the $n$s on the left hand side have to cancel out - so we have to have $$x=-y.$$ Aha! Now that simplifies to get $$x+(-x)(-1)=1,$$ that is, $$x={1\over 2}$$ and so $$y=-{1\over 2}.$$